# Let $f(z)= \frac {z^3}{(z+1)(z-2)}$. Find maximal $R$, minimal $r$ s.t. $f$ is holomorphic in $r \lt |z+1| \lt R$. Find $f's$ Laurant Series there

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)= \frac {z^3}{(z+1)(z-2)}$. Find maximal $R$, minimal $r$ s.t. $f$ is holomorphic in $r \lt |z+1| \lt R$. Find $f's$ Laurant Series there

So I got $f(z)= \frac {z^2}{3} \cdot \frac {1}{1+z}-\frac {z^2}{3} \cdot \frac {1}{1-\frac {z}{2}}$, which I can develop a Laurant series. However I get that $r=0$ and $R=1$ with this result. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, the second is wrong. It's often helpful to substitute $w=z+1$ in this sort of thing, and then you are dealing with easier series to understand. Then we are looking at $r<\lvert w \rvert<R$, and the function is
$$ f(w-1) = \frac{(w-1)^3}{w(w-3)} = \frac{(w-1)^3}{3} \left( \frac{1}{w-3} - \frac{1}{w} \right). $$
The second fraction, after the bracket is multiplied out, is an analytic function of $w$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, since you end up with a $1/w$ at the end, as well as a polynomial.

Similarly, the first fraction is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{3\}$. Hence the whole expression is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,3\}$, and the largest annulus of the form specified centred at $0$ containing neither of these is $0<\lvert w \rvert < 3$.